# regsvr32 DllRegisterServer failed

Tags: windows, activex, registration

one of my ActiveX controls fails to register. The component compiles, but then when I try to run

```
regsvr32 C:\...\component.ocx
```

I get an error window:

> RegSvr32 "DllRegisterServer in C:...\component.ocx failed. Return
>   code was: 0xe0434352".

The operating system is WinXP and I'm logged in as Administrator.

I've tried to run the component with the Visual Studio 10 debugger, but no breakpoints are reached.

Dependency walker shows warnings for IESHIMS.DLL, WER.DLL, and MPR.DLL.

Any ideas, what's going on here?

Thanks,
Micha

Comment: It is a low-level CLR exception.  Managed code.  Not sure how managed code ended up inside an .ocx file, but for one [ComVisible] managed assemblies need to be registered with Regasm.exe.  Contact the owner of the component for support.

Comment: Funny enough, I am the owner. I took over maintenance for this project from some other company. The call with Regasm.exe returned: RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not load file or assembly '<component>, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Could not find or load a type. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131522)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out setting /GF solved the problem (Project->Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Enable String Pooling).

My suspicion is that the component used too many Symbols (>64k). That's what I found for the error message I got from running Regasm.exe (see the comments above).
With string pooling that seems to be resolved.

I didn't have to change to using Regasm.exe, I still register the component with regsvr32.exe.